# How to parse unique records and their row index

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of files, some have no suffix and some with different suffixes. I would like to segregate the file names irrespective of their suffixes and list them along with the range of their row indices in the same spreadsheet. Below is the example and my failed code. Also attached the spreadsheet snapshot. Can you please help? Any new code/logic is welcome.

Input:

| Row index | Filename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | File1 |
| 2 | File2_a |
| 3 | File2_b |
| 4 | File2_c |
| 5 | File3_a |
| 6 | File3_b |

Output:

| Filename | Row indices range |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| File1 | 1 | 1 |
| File2 | 2 | 4 |
| File3 | 5 | 6 |

VBA code

```
Sub GetUniqueFiles()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            
    lastrow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    SameFile = False ' Flag to compare 2 consecutive file names
    i = 3: j = 3
    While i <= (lastrow - 1)
            name_curt = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
            name_next = sh.Range("B" & i + 1).Value
            file_curt = Split(name_curt, "_")(0)
            file_next = Split(name_next, "_")(0)
                        
            If file_curt <> file_next Then
                sh.Range("D" & j).Value = file_curt
                k1 = i
                sh.Range("E" & j).Value = k1
                sh.Range("F" & j).Value = k2
                i = i + 1: j = j + 1
            ElseIf file_curt = file_next Then
                SameFile = True
                sh.Range("B" & j).Value = file_curt
                k1 = i
                While SameFile
                    i = i + 1
                    name_curt = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
                    name_next = sh.Range("B" & i + 1).Value
                    file_curt = Split(name_curt, "_")(0)
                    file_next = Split(name_next, "_")(0)
                Wend
          
            End If
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

[image: Get unique file names]

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)
• What is your question? What's wrong with your code? What does your code versus what did you expect? Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub GetUniqueFiles()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, m, indx, rw As Range, f As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rw = sh.Range("A3:B3")                              'first input row
    
    r = 2 'start row for output
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) = 2                     'loop while have data
        indx = rw.Cells(1).Value
        f = Split(rw.Cells(2).Value, "_")(0)                ' "base" file name
        m = Application.Match(f, sh.Columns("D"), 0)        'see if already listed
        If IsError(m) Then                                  'not already listed ?
            sh.Cells(r, "D").Value = f                      'write file name
            sh.Cells(r, "E").Value = indx                   'write "first seen" index
            m = r
            r = r + 1
        End If
        sh.Cells(m, "F").Value = indx                       'write "last seen" index
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)                            'next input row
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Surely it's better to avoid all the range twiddling? For example, my answer below...

Comment: @ExcelHero - I think sometimes if performance is not an issue it's best to use code which is more likely to be understandable to the OP - if they're not used to dealing with arrays, then a simpler approach which is not noticeably slow might be more useful to them.

Comment: Depends entirely on the list length. It's best to learn the performant way since long lists will ultimately always raise their pesky heads.

Comment: @TimWilliams: can you please elaborate which part of the script handles the start row of the output list? This code prints on row 2 and I need to start from a different one.

Comment: Made a slight edit to add the output starting row.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without VBA. Add something like this in column C:

```
=LEFT(B2,IFERROR(FIND("_",B2)-1,LEN(B2)+1))
```

It will cut the underscore and everything after it. Next step is counting the distinct values. I would go for a pivot table, but there are lots of other ways.

Comment: Thanks Sam, that could also works, but how can I get the corresponding rows (begin-end) for each file?

Comment: In the D column: `=IF(C2<>C3,A2,D1)`

Comment: Thank you Sam, the last condition does not make sense to me. There are 2 cells that need to be satisfied : Start Row and End Row. I like this solution which skips VBA but getting the start and end row indices for unique values is a challenge

Comment: Roughly - if the value in "current C" differs from "next C", it's a new group. If it's a new group, take the row num from column A, otherwise pick it from the row above.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range` or `From within sheet`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***M Code***

```
let

//Change table name in next line to actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table22"]}[Content],

//split on the underscore and remove the splitted suffix
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Filename", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("_", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Filename", "Filename.2"}),

//set data types -- frequently a good idea in PQ
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{
        {"Filename", type text}, {"Filename.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Filename.2"}),

//Group by file name and extract the lowest and highest rows
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Filename"}, {
        {"Start Row", each List.Min([Row index]), type number}, 
        {"End Row", each List.Max([Row index]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For execution speed and resource conservation it's best to minimize interaction with the worksheet from VBA. For example the following references the worksheet precisely twice no matter how long the list of files. Don't underestimate the value of restricting worksheet interaction from VBA.

```
Sub GetUniqueFiles()
    Dim c&, i&, a$, b$, vIn, vOut

    Const FILES_IN$ = "b3"
    Const FILES_OUT$ = "d3"
    
    With Range(FILES_IN)
        vIn = .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(vIn), 1 To 3)
        
    For i = 1 To UBound(vIn)
        b = Split(vIn(i, 1), "_")(0)
        If a <> b Then
            a = b
            c = c + 1
            vOut(c, 1) = b
            vOut(c, 2) = i
            If c > 1 Then vOut(c - 1, 3) = i - 1
        End If
    Next
    If c > 1 Then vOut(c, 3) = i - 1
    
    Range(FILES_OUT).Resize(UBound(vIn), 3) = vOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Please have a look at this.